# Autowired giving NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, nullpointerexception

I have an Exception class:

```
@Component  
public class PushDataException extends RuntimeException {

@Autowired
private PushDataTraceLogService pushDataTraceLogService;
```

Somehow, while trying to use `pushDataTraceLogService`, I am getting null pointer, while
`PushDataTraceLogService` class looks like below:

```
public interface PushDataTraceLogService { 
    void save(PushDataTraceLog pushDataTraceLog);
```

which is getting implemented in class `PushDataTraceLogServiceImpl`:

```java
@Service
public class PushDataTraceLogServiceImpl implements PushDataTraceLogService {

    @Autowired
    private PushDataTraceLogRepository pushDataTraceLogRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(PushDataTraceLog pushDataTraceLog) {
        pushDataTraceLogRepository.save(pushDataTraceLog);
        PushDataTraceLog.destroy();
    }
}
```

pushDataTraceLog is not null, pushDataTraceLogService is giving null pointer

[null pointer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4KuN.png)

stack trace giving

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.util.PushDataException.setTraceLog(PushDataException.java:60)
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.util.PushDataException.<init>(PushDataException.java:52)
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.service.impl.AuthExposeAPIServiceImpl.validateToken(AuthExposeAPIServiceImpl.java:127)
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.controller.PushDataController.savePushDataBuilds(PushDataController.java:67)
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.controller.PushDataController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$61a69129.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at com.publicissapient.kpidashboard.apis.pushdata.controller.PushDataController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6ea830e.savePushDataBuilds(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
```

Comment: @Abra no pushDataTraceLog has data, the pushDataService is throwing null pointer

Comment: Can you also show repository i.e. pushDataTraceLogRepository